# In Wordpress how can I display only the child-categories and not the parents using wp_list_categories

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wp-list-categories

Ok so I have categories and sub categories to them.

Categories:

Honda

-Civic

-Accord

Toyota

-Camery

-Corrola

Nissan

-Maxima

-Versa

Now I want to display only 5 of those Sub_Categories randomly using wp-list-categories. I went through all of the args but still cant figure this out.

So I would want to see randomly:

- Versa
- Civic
- Camery
- Maxima
- Corrola

(with out showing the parent of Honda, Nissan and so forth)

How can this be done? or if it cannot with wp_list_categories then is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

using `get_terms` might be a better approach:

```
// get all terms
$terms = get_terms( 'category' );

// shuffle!
shuffle( $terms );

foreach( array_slice( $terms, 0, 5) as $term ){

    // skip top level terms
    if( 0 == $term->parent )
        continue;

    echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term, 'category' ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: That does output the child but it doesn't link to that child's category and how would I be able to only display 5?

Comment: You can extract a portion of the array with `array_slice` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and link the terms with `get_term_link()` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link)

Comment: iv never used those functions before mind giving me an example?